# Wait for a view to load and then do something angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a mean stack in my program goes like this:

```
view:
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="HomeController">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="player in data.user.myClub.myPlayers">
                <div class="player">
                    <div class="player_name">someone</div>
                    <img ng-src="modules/core/img/client/slider/player_on.png" alt="">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In the controller i have a jquery plugin (swapper) which should see a number of div with certain class and then compile them, problem is sometime the view is still not ready...

I have read something like this:

```
function SomeController($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {window.scrollTo(0,90);});
}
```

It doesn't seem to work properly... What are my options here?

Comment: viewContentLoaded works fine only if content is placed inside ng-view.

Comment: Another option is use ng-init to call method.

Comment: What does it mean inside ng-view? ui-view doesn't count?

Comment: content is rendered inside ng-view directive of angular.

Comment: angular.element(document).ready(function () {
          
            var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
                        ...
        }); Not working

Comment: @totothegreat personally I believe its not duplicate question..

Answer (score 1):

You can call method using mg-int at page load. I think this will solve your issue:
JS:

```
$scope.callMethod = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0,90);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" ng-init="callMethod()">
```

Or, another option is use the `angular.element(document).ready()`method to attach callbacks for when the document is ready..
Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready) post also.

Comment: Both of them methods don't do what i need, the only way i can do it is telling a timeout to do it after 100 milliseconds which is not good, anything else?

Comment: @totothegreat  It will do . Your approach may have some mistake. timeout is not a solution and it is also not a acceptable approach.