# Callback function after dom is loaded in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a code snippet in HTML where I am doing ng-repeat to get a list of boxes.
Once dom is ready I need to call a jquery plugin for resizing.
But before dom gets ready,plugin gets called and nothing is rendered.

Can anyone please help me,as how can I be notified that dom is updated or when dom is ready so that I can call my plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code ? It's better to put your script tags at the end of `body` tag

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `angular.element(document).ready()` method to attach callbacks for when the document is ready. We can simply attach the callback in the controller like so

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Hello World');
    });
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cVsdp/4/)

Taken From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646795/2025923

Comment: Be aware that this only works in the page load. If you are using ng-view / ui-view this approach will not be the better solution. It seems that the question look for a dom ready after ng-repeat finish teh rendering

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a way to be notified when ng-repeat is done with rendering the content. You can create a directive like this.

```
app.directive('ngRepeatEnd', function($rootScope){
                return {
                    restrict:'A',                   
                    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
                        if(scope.$last){                                
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('ArrayUpdated');                      
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
```

Since the directive operates in the same scope as ng-repeat, you can access the `$last` variable provided by ng-repeat. $last would be true for the last repeated value. So, with this, we can broadcast an event and catch it in the controller.

```
app.controller('DefaultController', function($scope){
      $scope.$on('ArrayUpdated', function(){
            //Your callback content here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I want to be notified when ng-repeat is done rendering.From where should I call directive ngRepeatEnd ?Can you please provide any example fiddle