# How to load AngularJS first when using JQuery as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angularjs and JQuery in the same project. When using Angularjs and JQuery in the same project, it is a convention that JQuery has to be loaded first and then AngularJS as follows:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

But it causing some problem as when page load, some html element hidden with AngularJS ng-hide directive becomes visible (for a while/during the time of JQuery load) until AngularJS load.

Problem will be solved if I can load AngularJS before JQuery!!

Is it somehow possible to load AngularJS before JQuery or any other solution for solving the problem described above.

**Any suitable solution will be highly appreciated!!**

Comment: My first question would be this: if you're using Angular, why are you using full-blown jQuery?

Comment: For some JQuery Animation!!

Comment: I'm guessing you tried switched the order of the script tags, right?

Comment: Yes!! But Jquery Doesn't work then!!

Comment: You should be initializing your components onload so that the funtion gets called after they both load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready

Answer (score 2):

There is a directive `ng-cloak` specifically for this purpose.

Just assign it along with `ng-show/ng-hide` elements on your first view.

```
<div ng-show="condition" ng-cloak>hello</div>
<div ng-hide="condition" ng-cloak>world</div>
```

Comment: Give an simple please!

Comment: Add this to your stylesheet if you aren't loading AngularJs in the `<head>` section: `[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}` to avoid flicker

Answer (score 0):

You can run JQuery in noConflict mode.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **settimeout** function in angularjs or jquery functions which can be loaded after all basic html are loaded i.e try to set time(say 1000 or 2000) value for angularjs functions after html loaded

[see setTimeout function page for usage](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout)