# AngularJS - Execute directive after DOM has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been reading lots of question for hours on StackOverflow but still not reach the solution.

I have to add `class="active"` to a sibling element after DOM has finished rendering. I wrote a directive to do that and put in it `$timeout()` with 0 delay but it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('updateTextField', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            $timeout(function(){
                var label = element.siblings('label');
                label.addClass('active');
                console.log(label); //for debugging purposes
            }, 0);
        }
    }
})
```

The result of `console.log('label')` is an element with the class `active` but if I inspect it directly, it hasn't class active.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run function in angular controller on document ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready)

Comment: Nope, I'm asking for directive that's different from controller so the question you posted don't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add just class after DOM rendering then you could do like this

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var id = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    id.className += "active";
});
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: I need to add that class in the sibling element, not in a div that wraps the element. Anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: @MatteoMeil then you could add the id to that sibling element.

Comment: I still have the same problem. The result is the same I wrote in question (last part)