# Styling table after the DOM has completed rendering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to styling table after the table fill with data. 
actually, after the DOM fully rendered.
How am I doing that in angularjs?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible dublicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angular-controller-on-document-ready)

Comment: The AngularJS rendering life-cycle is very complex. Directives such as `ng-view` and `ng-repeat` render DOM only after data has been received from the server. The question is too broad to identify a specific answer.