# How can I pass value from Angular to javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. The following code prints the right user email (`"my_email@domain.com"`) but in the javascript alert it shows `"{{user_name}}"`instead of `"my_email@domain.com"`.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController" id="id123">
{{user_name}}
</div>
<script> var to_print=document.getElementById('id123').innerText; alert(to_print) </script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: While you already have an answer, my suggestion would be to put the code inside your angular controller, in the angularJs document ready event. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646795/7029064 for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code is load before the angular. So, the value of {{username}} is not found. Use SetTimeout to wait for the angular code to load.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController" id="id123">
{{user_name}}
</div>
<script> 
setTimeout(function(){
           var to_print=document.getElementById('id123').innerText; 
           alert(to_print)
          }),1000); 
</script>
```

Hope!!it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Vishal, Thank you for your support. when I changed the code as you advised, the issue is still not solved. Now, both the code and the javascript alert show {{user_name}}.

Comment: I corrected a typo as below but now the alert is not triggered :
```
<script>
        setTimeout(function(){
           var to_print=document.getElementById('id123').innerText;
           alert(to_print);
          },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: My bad!!  Your solution works. thank you very much.

Comment: You need to put this code inside the controller to ensure it will be executed after angular completes its initialization.

Comment: Surely there must be a better way to know when Angular is initialized than arbitrarily wait an amount of time and hope?