# AngularJs waith before dom content loaded

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide and create elements that are loaded by AngularJS.

The `DOM` is not entirely loaded when I'd like to execute my JS functions.

**Issue :** my query selector is not able to detect elements. And I don't want to use a `timeout` because it depends to the network of the user.

**My code :**

```
app.controller('RootController', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    // NULL here, but after dom loaded in the chrome console I get an array of elements
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('table .actionslist'));
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646756/how-to-run-function-in-angularjs-controller-on-document-ready

Comment: What do you wish to do with the elements? Maybe there is a more *angular* way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code;

This will add a listener on viewContentLoaded and will execute the code inside it when DOM is fully loaded.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {  
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('table .actionslist'));
});
```