# AngularJS ng-include: onload calling a function defined in included controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Using AngularJS, is it possible to use the "onload" argument to trigger a function defined inside a "child" controller (a controller called by the included template)?

Example:

```
<!-- parent container -->
<div ng-include="'/path/template.html'" onload="childOnLoad()"></div>

<!-- template.html -->
<div ng-controller="childController">   
    <p ng-bind="txt"></p>
</div>

<!-- childController.js -->
app.controller('childController', function($scope) {    
    $scope.txt = "Test text";

    $scope.childOnLoad = function() {
        alert("Loaded!");
    };  
});
```

Does it make sense?
Or should I simply call the function inside the childController, as in the following?

```
<!-- childController.js -->
app.controller('childController', function($scope) {    
    $scope.txt = "Test text";

    $scope.childOnLoad = function() {
        alert("Loaded!");
    };

    $scope.childOnLoad();   
});
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load

Comment: So... do you suggest to simply call $scope.childOnLoad() inside the child controller?

Comment: Yes I would just call the `$scope.childOnLoad()` function inside the controller. Until angular adds another directive specifically for `onload` events.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to mention is that if your `childOnLoad` function simily initializes variables, you might even be better off removing it altogther and initializing in the main body directly.

Answer (score 3):

Leave the parent container the way you defined it:

```
<div ng-include="'/path/template.html'" onload="childOnLoad()"></div>
```

In the parent controller define:

```
$scope.childOnLoad() {
  $scope.$broadcast("childOnLoad", data);
}
```

and in the child controller:

```
$scope.$on("childOnLoad", function (event, data) {
  alert("Loaded!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, I did not know I could do that, It saved my day, It worked fine when calling child controller from parent controller, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your second attempt you did right: you are creating some functions, the scope of that controller is taking those functions as properties, then $scope.childOnLoad(); will call the function you created.

In fact you can define so many functions but they are not called while loading or when loads complete.