# Issue with AngularJS scope in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code of my view and an abstract of code in my controller.

View:

```
<div id="search_results" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="result in results">{{result.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
   myapp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope,SearchF) {    
      $scope.launch_search = function() {
         SearchF.update(function() {
            $scope.results = SearchF.get();
         });
      }
   })
```

The function .get() returns my data, but the view does not update. Looks like my scope ($scope.results) does not refer to the general scope. If I write the .update() block outside of the launch_search function, the view updates fine.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` is an async call, if it's using `ngResource`, assign the data in the callback:

```
 SearchF.get({}, function(data) {
     $scope.results = data;
 });
```

Comment: get() is not async, it just returns a data from a factory that was fetched by update() (which is async indeed). Check out my own answer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user1491411 -- So, `update` is async, and that stores data in the `SearchF` service - and the `get()` simply pulls the stored data? Can you post the `searchF` service?

Comment: Exactly. No need to put the code here, the problem was a scope one, see my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `$scope.$parent.results` to reference the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

Off course some one has to trigger your function right ?

put a button with `ng-click="launch_search()"`, on click of that your view updates. In case you want the view to be updated on load check out

[How to execute angular controller function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load)

Comment: Yes something else is triggering the call, see my own answer to the question. Thanks a lot for your help.