# Angular run function on broadcast and page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a controller as below, with an `.$on` attribute that is called via `.$broadcast` when a form is submitted.  I'd also like the event to run when the controller loads.  Is there a syntactically easy way to go about doing this, or will I have to add a `on page load` listener?

```
myApp.controller('DownloadsCloudCtrl', ['$scope', 
                                        '$rootScope', 
                                        'requestService',
  function($scope, $rootScope, requestService){
  $scope.title = 'Most Popular Keywords';
  $scope.tooltip = 'Test tooltip';
  $rootScope.$on('updateDashboard', function(event, month, year) {
    requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {
      $scope.d3Data = data;
    });
  });
}]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when the page loads for the first time*? Why not just run your desired code when the controller loads?

Comment: Sure, sorry that is a better way of putting it.  I'd like it to run when the controller loads.

Comment: Same question as Matt.  Couldn't you just broadcast when you load the controller?

Comment: Oh I see... is that the best way to solve it?  If so then thanks

Comment: It seems pretty clean to use the broadcast.  I would probably consider putting the broadcast in a service that all of the controllers could share.  But that is more a style issue.

Comment: Okay.  If I add a `broadcast` line inside the controller, I'll have to call it with the `$cookieStore` values since the `broadcast` isn't inside the form.  Kind of lame, extra code than I would've wanted, but it seems like it's the best way (outside of creating a whole new service).

Comment: Well, here is another question like yours

[angular on pageload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this when your controller loads, then this is extremely simple. Basically remove your `$on` logic into its own function and call it inside the controller init:

```
myApp.controller('DownloadsCloudCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'requestService',
function($scope, $rootScope, requestService){
    $scope.title = 'Most Popular Keywords';
    $scope.tooltip = 'Test tooltip';

    var updateDash = function(month, year) {
        requestService.getP2PKeywordData(month, year).then(function(data) {
            $scope.d3Data = data;
        });
    };

    $rootScope.$on('updateDashboard', function(event, month, year) {
        // run the update function
        updateDash(month, year);
    });

    // run the update function once when the controller loads
    updateDash(someMonth, someYear);
}]);
```

Now this would be much better abstracted as a service, but this should at least get you started.