# Submit form on page load in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, onload

I would like to submit a search form on page load if search terms were specified in the route. The problem is that `searchForm` isn't defined yet when `search()` runs. I've seen others get this to work by putting ng-controller right on the form element, but I have multiple forms on this page, so the controller has to be a parent of the forms.

How can I ensure the form is defined when I call search()?

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.model = {searchTerms: ""};

  $scope.search = function(){
      if($scope.searchForm.$valid){
          ...
      }
  };

  if($routeParams.terms !=""){
      $scope.model.searchTerms = $routeParams.terms;
      $scope.search();
  }
}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="searchForm" ng-submit="search()">
      ...
  </form>
  <form name="detailForm" ng-submit="save()">
      ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15463124/1230075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    if($routeParams.terms !=""){
        $scope.model.searchTerms = $routeParams.terms;
        $scope.search();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using `$watch` on searchForm?

```
if($routeParams.terms != "") {
    var unregister = $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.searchForm;
    }, function() {
        // might want to wrap this an if-statement so you can wait until the proper change.
        unregister(); //stop watching
        $scope.model.searchTerms = $routeParams.terms;
        $scope.search();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have multiple forms I'd rather not need multiple watches. I posted a solution that seems to do the trick.