# Directive not rendering after $http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I began working with angularjs and have a problem.

**app.js (just the relevant route)**

```
$routeProvider.when('/search', {templateUrl: 'partials/search-results.html', controller: 'SearchController', title: 'Product Search'});
```

**search-results.html**

```
<div product-list></div>
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="page_content_offset p_bottom_0">
    <div class="container mh600">
         <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**product-list.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>{{item.address_components[0].long_name}}</p>
  </div>
```

**controller.js just relevant code:**

```
$scope.search = function() {

$scope.loading = true;
$scope.items = {};

ProductSearchService.searchItems($scope.term).then(function(data) {
  $scope.items = data;
  $scope.loading = false;
});
};
```

**directives.js (just relevant code)**

```
directive('productList', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'partials/list/product-list.html'
        };
```

My Problem now is:
The ProductSearchService loads the data. But the directive not rendering as expected.

If i move the directive code from search-results.html to my index.html like this:

```
 <div class="page_content_offset p_bottom_0">
      <div class="container mh600">
       <div product-list></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

evrything is rendered nicely. So i think i included my directive wrongly or forgot something important.

I've created a plunkr similar to my setup:

http://plnkr.co/edit/60dvyFnz74yrsK12J2J4?p=preview

Everything works fine in that.

**In my local application i changed the "product-list.html" model property access to this**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $parent.items">
    <p>{{item.address_components[0].long_name}}</p>
  </div>
```

**Update controllers.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('SearchController', ['$scope','$http','ProductSearchService', function($scope, $http, ProductSearchService) {

                $scope.items = {};

                $scope.search = function() {

                    $scope.loading = true;

                    ProductSearchService.searchItems($scope.term).then(function(data) {
                        $scope.items = data;
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    });
                };
}]);
```

**Update 2:**
I now have a plnkr where the problem can be shown:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QgU1cf3JeJYKu6Fkl9zv?p=preview

Comment: no console error appears

Comment: Can you make a plnkr to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set any scope attribute to your directive.
This means that your directive use the defining/containing scope as the directive own scope.
Thus , the scope that is used in product-list.html is the same as the one used by search-result.html (and so by the SearchController).

The only reason , you could have to use the $parent.items would be if you specified     scope:{}, in your directive.You can even test it in your plunker (I did).
Can you double check the directive scope attribute ?

Thx

Comment: Hey, i now have a working plnkr where i can show the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/QgU1cf3JeJYKu6Fkl9zv?p=preview 
If i remove the $scope.items = {}; statement from my SearchController the scope then seems to be the same and i don't have to use $parent. But im still confused?

Comment: In your plnkr you use 2 searchController: one for index.html (in body ng-controller="SearchController") and one for search-result.html (in your $routeProvider config). But you only call the search function of index.html (in ng-init="init()").As a matter of fact , the uninitialized scope.items value of search-result.html is shadowing the valued scope.items definition of index.html.See my [version](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgbhWo0odLSHa850zSFM?p=preview) and take care of not using ng-init to initialize a controller (as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15463124/1170805) )

Answer (score 0):

```
directive('productList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '<section data-ng-include=" 'partials/list/product-list.html' "></section>'

    };
});
```

try this one as the directive :)

Comment: I found a solution which works but cant explain myself why this works.
I changed the access to model proeprties from items to $parent.items. Now it works ???

Comment: do you have a controller for `product-list.html` ?

Comment: yes i have a controller called SearchController. I've updates my question and wrote the relevant code under: Update controllers.js

Comment: that is the case data is in the enclosing controller of that so if u want to access a parent controller property u can user $parent or try something phototypical inheritace in javascript :)