# Why directive is not rendered correctly when using variable initializers

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have the following plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9SjDSb5AjKwXNRGRrpdO?p=preview

If i remove the initialized vars:

```
Line 72: $scope.totalItems = 0;
Line 73: $scope.currentPage = 1;
```

My Controller uses a service and from the response i want to update the angular ui bootstrap pagination directive. This doesn't work until i remove the both lines above.

Comment: I think the answer is the same as here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25606783/979555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the execution of the $scope.search function at the end of the controller:

```
Line95: $scope.search();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QIuuxvU02FT00riiKPf2?p=preview

The "init" function is just another function in the scope, is not being executed at start of the controller.

Comment: The "init" function is just another function in the scope, is not being executed at start of the controller.