# Does a function gets invoked automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function `sendData()`. My question is can it get executed without invoking it, inside the controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js - how to execute function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/angular-js-how-to-execute-function-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can call it just after declaration.

```js
var sendData = function() {
  //dostuff
}
sendData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your method in self execution name function.

```
var sendData = (function _() {
  // your stuff

  return _;
})();
```

It will directly executes and you can also later call it using `sendData()`

Comment: aahhh cool!! i was always curious of difference between the above two methods!! thanks !! :)