# triggering a bound event on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not quite sure if this is an anti-pattern maybe someone could shed some light on if there us a better way of doing it.

I have bound a re-size event on the window and also want to trigger the same code on load. IS this the correct way to do this?

```
angular.element($window).bind("resize", function (event) {

    // code here

}).trigger("resize");
```

fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/6g49zo7n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to extract the shared code to a single function and call that function from both event types. So it would look like:

```
function resize(event) {
    // do the resize
}


angular.element($window).bind("resize", resize);

/* now call resize on init the angular way */
```

To call resize on load the Angular way, take a look at: [execute function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/execute-function-on-page-load).