# onload equivalent in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onload

Im trying to hide images loading until they are completed and cant figure out how to do that easily in Angular. Can onload call a function in the scope? Or is there a better way to do this?
ng-init doesnt work

Comment: Load them via `$http` and as the AJAX call completes, use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute function on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/execute-function-on-page-load)

Comment: thats a good idea, Ill try it thanks

Comment: page load events won't help you in angular.... you need to use `onload` event of each image element. My bet is there is already a simple directive around for this...but is also easy to create

Comment: Does the `ng-src` directive solve your problem? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: no unfortunately, i'm using ng-src but theyre stll visibly downloading.