# AngularJS: Execute a JavaScript script after the page has loaded

Tags: angularjs, document-ready

I have to customize a platform designed in ASPX and AngularJS.
I only have access to the HTML and CSS code, I do not have access to the AngularJS controller.

I want to add a small JavaScript script, but I encounter a problem when I integrate it on the platform.

I cannot detect when the page is loaded.
If I use the javascript (window.onload) or jQuery ($(document).ready) functions, it doesn't work.

Since I don't have access to the AngularJS controller, do I have a way of knowing when the page is loaded?

Thank you
Florian

Comment: I think your post is concerning AngularJS. Can you correct the tags? Avoid to tag your post AngularJS and Angular, they're completely different.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is rather AngularJS. Thank you

Comment: No solutions or ideas?

Comment: Maybe this post should help you: [How to execute AngularJS controller function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/how-to-execute-angularjs-controller-function-on-page-load)