# Integrate Salesforce Einstein chatbot in website built using Dot Net and Angular

Tags: salesforce, chatbot, salesforce-lightning, sfdc, salesforce-einstein

I am trying to add chatbot feature to my website (built using .Net and Angular). So, I am thinking of using Salesforce Einstein Chatbot for it. But is it possible to add Einstein chatbot feature to my website as I don't see any results on google on how to integrate Einstein chatbot to external website built using .Net and Angular.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing special about Angular and out of the box chat uses only Salesforce, there's no .NET integration. What have you tried so far, what problems/errors you have? We are not a magical free code writing service.

After you finish configuring the bot you end up with a piece of JavaScript code you have to put on your site (can be in otherwise plain html page or Angular app or whatever)

If you don't have the bot yet, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/service_bots_basics and https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-an-einstein-bot are good start.

Once you have it, go to Setup -> Embedded Service Deployments and you should find piece of HTML to inject into any page you want.

[image: schreenshot of sample autogenerated code]

You might have to "Angularize" it, put the initialisation into page load event ([How to execute AngularJS controller function on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458609/how-to-execute-angularjs-controller-function-on-page-load) `ng-init`? I don't know, I'm not Angular dev), maybe move styles to separate file.

Comment: so if the chat code is pasted to a website, the bot would be functional on that website? Did you have to enter the url of the website anywhere in salesforce or were the configurations on the trailheads sufficient? My bot is functional on the bot builder, so would I have to create any extra configurations?

Comment: Yes, you need to make SF "trust" chat requests coming from your website. Seriously, it's in these trailhead modules. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-an-einstein-bot/prep-for-einstein-bots search for "For Website URL, paste the URL you copied from your community." (you need to adapt this to your situation, it's a crash course training after all)

Comment: alright thanks! I struggled with finding documentation but that helped a bunch!